# Checking if value exists in table not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, exists

I am trying to write a script to insert values from an XML file into an SQL database.

However i can not get the script to correctly check if a value already exists in the SQL database.

heres my current code:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories_description` WHERE categories_name`='$qCategory'");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "cat exists";
}
else if($qCategory != ""){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `categories` (`categories_id`, `categories_image`, `parent_id`, `sort_order`, `date_added`, `last_modified`, `categories_status`) VALUES ('$catid', NULL, '0', NULL, NULL, NULL, '1');");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `categories_description` (`categories_id`, `language_id`, `categories_name`, `categories_description`) VALUES ('$catid', '1', '$qCategory', '$qCategory');");
$catid +=1;
}
```

I have tried tons of things to get this to work, but it just doesn't want to.
The problem I am having is if I have duplicate value it will insert it anyway.
Does anyone know how to fix this? or what it going wrong?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The biggest mistake I can spot with your code is that you do not do any error checking. Mysql returns errors and gives even descriptions. But you're not making use of these features so you're sitting alone in the dark. http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/19/8/6

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix this line first, you missed ` at the beginning of categories_name:

```
"SELECT * FROM `categories_description` WHERE categories_name`='$qCategory'"
```

Comment: haha, its always the simple things.

Comment: Display the error as suggested by hakre, it'll help you a lot debugging. ;)